# SeekBar NO initial value

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to display a seekbar in android with no initial value. This means that there is no circle button at first, it only appears when the user taps the bar. Is this possible?

I think it should be something implying the attribute 'thumb'.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with

```
seekbar.setProgress(0);
Drawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
seekbar.setThumb(transparentDrawable);
```

And when the user touches the seekbar (public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar))
change the Thumb again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in your layout

```
android:progress="0"
```

or Programmatically

```
 seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.yourSeekBar);
 seekbar.setProgress(0);
```

However this won't remove the circle of which you are talking about.This will just ensure that your `SeekBar`'s intial value is set to 0.For other properties refer [Documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the view class:

```
init {
    [...]
    seekBar.thumb.alpha = 0 // range: 0 - 255
}
```

In the listener class:

```
override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
    seekBar.thumb.alpha = 255 // range: 0 - 255
    [...]
}
```